# ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got SYSTEM.ADDRESSTYPE

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create type AddressType as object
(
house_no number(3), 
street varchar2(30),
town varchar2(20),
postcode varchar2(8),
country varchar2(2)
);
```

NB: that is my AddressType attributes

I create the table below and inserted the following records in which i received the mentioned error in return

```
create table players
(

player_no number(2),
player_first_name varchar2(30),
player_initials varchar2(3),
player_last_name varchar2(25),
national_ranking number(2),
matches_won number(3),
home_address AddressType,
phone_number varchar2 (13),
primary key (player_first_name)
)

insert into players
values (2,'Bokamoso', 'B.M', 'Ramocha', 5, 8, AddressType('453, '12 Main Street', 'Mochudi', 'POB453', 'BW'), '75645345');

insert into players
values (3,'Kitso', 'K.M', 'Mathe', 7, 12, AddressType(531, '315 Kgoro Street', 'Malotwane', 'POB873', 'BW'), '72557084');

insert into players
values (1,'Thabiso', 'T.M', 'Mathe', 1, 45, AddressType(897, '036 Sandton Road, Johannesburg', 'POB676', 'SA'), '000776966928');

insert into players
values (5,'Muller', 'M.M', 'Medupe', 7, 13, AddressType(343, '4th Church Street', 'Pretoria', 'POB456', 'SA'), '024272665345');

insert into players
values (7,'Kennedy', 'K.L', 'Leburu', 8, 9, AddressType(245, '5th Avenue Bojale', 'Gaborone', 'POB532', 'BW'), '74530984');

insert into players
values (10,'Atang', 'A.K', 'Akanyang', 10, 22, AddressType(123, '2nd Avenue Bogwera', 'Francistown', 'POB843', 'BW'), '77909308');
```

Comment: Is this a typo? `AddressType(897, '036 Sandton Road, Johannesburg', 'POB676', 'SA')`
should be `AddressType(897, '036 Sandton Road', 'Johannesburg', 'POB676', 'SA')`

Comment: Thats part of the value i want to insert into the table

Comment: Tested your schema and insert queries, however I got no error.

Maybe `AddressType('453, '12 Main Street', 'Mochudi', 'POB453', 'BW')` is also a typo.
It should be `AddressType(453, '12 Main Street', 'Mochudi', 'POB453', 'BW')`

Comment: Just tried your recommendation but still it gives me the same error

Comment: Possibly similar issue as https://community.oracle.com/message/10385153#10385153
He says it's a bug.
What oracle version are you using?
I tested with oracle 11gR2.